# In a bit string of length 11, how do you find the probability of even number of zeros?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I thought about doing the complement but I wasn't sure if that was correct.
Or add up the different cases that there is an even number of 0's as the probability?

Comment: Are zeros and ones equally probable?

Comment: Add up the cases, e.g. 0,2,4,6,8,10, then divide by total.

Comment: Assume that they are equally probable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each string with $n$ zeroes, there is a complementary string with $11-n$ zeroes, obtained by changing all the `0`s to `1`s and vice versa.  When $n$ is even, $11-n$ is odd and vice versa.

So exactly half the strings have an even number of zeroes and the probability is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

If you toss a coin $11$ times, what's the probability of an even number of heads?

**Hint:** It always comes down to the last toss. What's the probability that it falls the way it has to, to make an even number of heads?

> For each string with $n$ zeros, there is a corresponding string with $n\pm1$ zeros, obtained by **flipping the last bit**; one is even, the other odd. Thus the probability of an even number of zeros is $\frac12$ (assuming ones and zeros are equally likely). This works for strings of any positive length.

Answer (score 0):

(This is how you get the answer if you don't have any clever ideas.)

For each $n$ between $0$ and $11$, there are exactly $\def\b#1{\binom{11}{#1}}\b n$ bit strings with $n$ zeroes.  There are therefore $$\b0 + \b2 + \b4 + \b6 + \b8 + \b{10}$$ strings with an even number of zeroes.

(At this point one could observe that since $\b n = \b{11-n}$, the sum above is also equal to the number of strings with an *odd* number of zeroes, which is essentially [the solution in my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689413/25554).  However, we continue with the brute-force answer.)

The expression above is equal to

$$1 + 55 + 330 + 462 + 165 + 11 = \color{darkred}{1024}$$

so the total probability is $$\frac{\color{darkred}{1024}}{2^{11}} = \frac12.$$

(One might also remember the following binomial identity: $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2i} = 2^{n-1}.)$$